# SVG favicon won't show up anymore

Tags: html, svg, favicon

I have the problem that my .svg favicon won't load anymore in any browser (IE, Edge, Chrome).
Cache is already cleared, also restarted Browser and tried Incognito-mode.

It's still reachable: [favicon](https://stats.kode-it.de/favicon_v1.svg)

[Link to website](https://stats.kode-it.de/)

Code in head-Tag:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon_v1.svg" sizes="any"/>
```

Some hours ago I tested it on an other pc with chrome (same version) and edge and it worked there. I changed some things in the code but not the favicon-code.

Does anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: It loads for me

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg), SVG favicons aren't anywhere near to being production-ready, why would you expect it to work in the first place?

You saying "doesn't work *anymore*" would suppose that you tested it with Firefox or Safari earlier, as those seem to be the only ones who kind-of support it.

Comment: I'm just wondering because the icon worked before without any problems.

Comment: @user6679493 check it with a browser that supports it, I happen to be on Firefox and as I mentioned, it works for me.